Kafka Connect - Oracle - No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
I'm facing an issue which I can not resolve when trying to breath life into a JdbcSourceConnector. I would like to create a secure connection to an Oracle DB with the following connection string:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=host)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
I get the following error:
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:752)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:256)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:84)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:54)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.start(JdbcSourceConnector.java:95)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:209)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:348)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:331)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:247)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:419)
        at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:241)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:157)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
        ... 20 more

Through the 1521/TCP the connection is succesful to Oracle, but I need the TCPS.
Kafka Connect runs as a systemd service in a RHEL 9.4 VM with java version openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS.
Kafka Connect version: 3.2.3 (with scala 2.13) from the opensource Kafka package
Using the following plugin for the connector: confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.6 (which contains the ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar)
I have truststore and keystore set in the environment variables from the service file, like this:
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore/keysotre.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password"
And the above are also set in the connect-distributed.properties like this:
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore/keysotre.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

The keystore is valid until: Wed May 06 08:21:03 CEST 2026
I tried the following without any success:

put the following in the service file: -Doracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites="(TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)" -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524796/9462623
replacing the ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar to ojdbc10.jar inside confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.6/lib/

The Oracle DBAs say all the TLSv1.2 ciphers are enabled from the Oracle side.
Does anyone have a clue how this could be resolved?
Thanks in advance for any help!

I think your issue is related to Oracle using an old sslcontext algorithm when building the sslcontext internally. So even though the cipher is supported it is not being used because old sslcontext algorithm is being used, see here which is probably causing the issue: https://github.com/mikesmithjr/ora-jdbc-source/blob/8a8331bc7112ecd8dfcf97afe9d27cb9c30e8b0d/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/net/nt/CustomSSLSocketFactory.java#L126
